# Halt parent script if directory missing in child script

Tags: shell

I have two script : Script1 : Gives a path(directory) as a input to another directory and script2 scan that directory and creates logs of any path or file in missing in that inout directory.Now i want to stop script1 if any path or file is missing however my second script should complete scanning whole directory(given as input).

In short my logs should be complete and my first script should be halt(in case of file missing)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 (my favorite):

Make sure, that script2 returns a proper exit code (typically 0, if everything is fine, and 1, if an error occurs, i.e. one of the files is missing). Query the exit code in Script1 and terminate Script1 if the exit code is not zero.

Method 2:

Have Script1 check the length of the log file created by script2. If the length is zero, or if the log file doesn't exist, terminate Script1.

Comment: how can I send the return_code(0 or 1) back to 1st script and gather it in 1st script?

Comment: With `exit 1`, respectively `exit 0`. In the calling script, you are using `if script2; then; ...` to distinguish the cases. The *then* part corresponds to exit code 0, the *else* part to exit code non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

That what I did :
In script one give a call to script two and in the next line caught the exit status of previous executable command(that is call two second script).
In he second script I maintained a flag to get the exit status.
In 1st script :

```
  $script_path/firstScript.sh 
  if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; then
    exit 1
  fi
```

In second script :

```
if [ "$errorCode" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "$(timestamp) INFO tid=\"$tid\"   ========== Success"
else
 echo "$(timestamp) INFO tid=\"$tid\"   ========== Script executed with errors,Check missing files ========== "
 echo "$(timestamp) INFO tid=\"$tid\"  Script executed with errors,Check logger for more information "
 exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I tried to reformat your code, so that it makes sense. I guess when your write `$script_path/firstScript.sh`, you really mean that what you call later "second script" is executed. Correct? Otherwise, I don't see where you are calling the *second* script...